# Element ref was specified as a string (clickAwayableElement) but no owner was set

Tags: reactjs

I'm following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHXPsSq6sf4) to use Material UI in ReactJS. On 31:28 in the video, after I add:

```
<Drawer open={this.state.open}>
    <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
</Drawer>
```

I meet this issue:

> Element ref was specified as a string (clickAwayableElement) but no
>   owner was set. You may have multiple copies of React loaded.

Comment: there might be multiple copies of react installed. One might be your own. other might be from one of the dependencies. try `npm ls react` and see wat is displayed.

Comment: reactchatroom@1.0.0 /Users/yindeyong
└── react@15.6.2

Answer (score 4):

I have met same problem in React.
This is my create-react-app.

```
├─node_modules
├─public
└─src
    ├─component
    │  └─react-bash
    │      └─node_modules
    └─lib
```

Only need One /node_modules dependency.
But I have other /node_modules dependency under the /src.
I deleted the /node_modules dependency under the /src,this problem be solved.

```
├─node_modules
├─public
└─src
    ├─component
    │  └─react-bash                                      
    └─lib
```

Comment: Your response is poorly worded. Please be specific and provide an example.

Comment: @sparkplug ok,I will give example

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in using react-bootstrap. As said in [it's getting started page](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/), i installed "react react-dom" packages before installing react-bootstrap, while i had already it installed in create-react-app.

uninstalling it solved me

```
npm uninstall  react react-dom
```

see: [Multiple copies of React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html#multiple-copies-of-react)